# Custom domain linking, but herokuapp persistent in address bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, cname

I've succeeded in getting `www.jamesdong.com` and `jamesdong.com` to point to `jamesdong.herokuapp.com`. The problem is that once you get there, the address bar shows `jamesdong.herokuapp.com` rather than `www.jamesdong.com` or `jamesdong.com`.

Any idea how I can fix this? Feel free to try to see the problem in your own browser, site is live.

For reference:

`heroku domains` shows 3 domains:

```
jamesdong.com
www.jamesdong.com
jamesdong.herokuapp.com
```

I'm using TigerTech as my domain name provider, the settings are as follows:

- DNS entry: www.jamesdong.com (I also tried using * in place of www as a wildcard, same problem resulted)
- Type: CNAME
- Data: jamesdong.herokuapp.com

And those are all the settings I can edit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up happening was that my DNS provider didn't allow ALIAS and CNAME changes so I put the below code in my application helper

```
 before_action :redirect_to_www if Rails.env == "production"

 def redirect_to_www
   unless /www\.jamesdong\.com/ =~ request.url
     uri = URI.parse(request.url)
     uri.host = "www.jamesdong.com"
     redirect_to uri.to_s
   end
 end
```

Comment: By application helper, I think you mean application controller! It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Configure it like this

```
  ALIAS jamesdong.com => jamesdong.herokuapp.com
  CNAME www.jamesdong.com => jamesdong.herokuapp.com
```

It will be fixed.

Comment: Interesting... so it works in IE, but not in Chrome... and I've cleared my history and cache... what browser are you using @ParitoshPiplewar?

Comment: Also, I've noticed that if you click a link for www.jamesdong.com, it works fine, but if you physically type it into the address bar, then when the page loads, the address bar morphs to jamesdong.herokuapp.com. Again this is only for Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, however, the only record types I can change are A, AAAA, CNAME, MX, NS, SRV, TXT, I don't have an ALIAS option...

Comment: Ah that won't do it, because I already own the domains names www.jamesdong.com and jamesdong.com I can't add them as potential aliases. Trying to submit just says that I already own it.

Comment: can't help. technically how to do it, i told you. I dont know what your DNS provider provide. I use dnsimple.com , it works best.

Comment: No problem, I think i'll call them on Monday... thanks for your help!